# I am trying to understand another programmer's ForEach statement

Tags: c#

When I try compiling the code below on VS2015, I get the following error:

> 'List int' does not contain a definition for 'ForEach'.

Please help, by converting the code below to a normal foreach (var in type) statement.

```
Enumerable.Range (0, 4).ToList ().ForEach (x =>
    dashboard.RowDefinitions.Add (
    new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength (1, GridUnitType.Star)
    }
));
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? That foreach is just executing the lambda action on each iteration (like having code inside a foreach loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for` is more readable and suitable here, because you don't use argument of `ForEach` method and have many usefull actions (`Range`, `ToList`).

```
for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
{
    dashboard.RowDefinitions.Add (
        new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength (1, GridUnitType.Star)}
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so muck #Backs. Your answer cleared the confusion, and my confusion was this part 'Enumerable.Range (0, 4).ToList ()' of the code.

Comment: Enumerable.Range (0, 4).ToList() is a list of int start from 0 and count 4 so you will get a list of [0,1,2,3] http://ideone.com/BCUiXp